# Error when adding DESCRIPTION file to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

recently I wanted to enable the Showcase mode on my Shiny app, which I uploaded to shinyapps.io. I looked at some other questions in this forum and created a DESCRIPTION file (no file extension) that looks like this:

> Title: XX
>
> Author: YY
>
> DisplayMode: Showcase
>
> Type: Shiny

As soon as I want to upload my App together with the Description file (using either the "publish" button provided by RStuio or using the "shinyapps::deployApp("XX",account="yy")" command), I get the following error (99999 is an edited number):

> Preparing to deploy application...DONE
>
> Uploading bundle for application: 99999...Error in readDcf(file.path(project, > "DESCRIPTION"))[, "Package"] :
>
> subscript out of bounds
>
> Calls:  ... suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers ->  -> unname
>
> Execution halted

I also tried adding/removing lines from the DESCRIPTION file, including the DisplayMode line, but it didn't help. Uploading the App without the Description file still works fine. Furthermore I completely uninstalled R and RStudio and reinstalled the newest versions (3.2.3 and 0.99.879). I am using Windows 10.

Also the app works fine and is in Showcase mode if I run it locally.

Any ideas what this could be about?

Thank you so much in advance,

Laurin